# SAS MACRO how to assign MACRO to date9

Tags: sas

I try to reassign macro to new macro, which I want to create date9.

so my code is this

```
    %Let CALYEAR   =2020;
    %let AYEAR     =%SYSEVALF(&CALYEAR-1);

    FALLSTART_ONE=%sysfunc(15AUG&AYEAR,date9.);
```

so I assume Macro variable "AYEAR" is 2019 and  I want to create macro variable "FALLSTART_ONE" =15AUG2019

but error is

```
212  FALLSTART_ONE=%sysfunc(15AUG&AYEAR,date9.);
     -------------
     180
ERROR: Function name missing in %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function reference.
```

How should I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: When using the macro variable in the context of a DATA step or other 'dated-ness' (`where`,etc...), you will need to express it as a date literal `"&FALLSTART_ONE"D`

Comment: When dealing with dates I generally recommend using INTNX() to increment your dates so you don't have to worry about weird boundary issues, such as incrementing months. You often don't need dates in the date9 format as well, unless you have it stored as a character field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `%let`. You also do not need to enclose it in `%sysfunc()`. You can build the string as-is.

```
%let FALLSTART_ONE=05AUG&AYEAR;
```